# Reverse an N-Dimensional array

Tags: code-golf, array, ragged-list

### Details

Write a function or program that, given an array (or list), containing only integers, returns or output an array with all sub-elements reversed. That is, reverse all elements of the deepest array, then the second deepest, etc. The dimensions need not be specified, but the function or program must work for [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) in your programming language's native format.

---

### Examples

**This:**

```
[[1,2], [3,4]]
```

**Would become this:**

```
[[4,3], [2,1]]
```

---

**This:**

```
[[[ 1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6], [ 7, 8, 9]],
 [[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]],
 [[19,20,21], [22,23,24], [25,26,27]],
 [[28,29,30], [31,32,33], [34,35,36]],
 [[37,38,39], [40,41,42], [43,44,45]],
 [[46,47,48], [49,50,51], [52,53,54]]]
```

**Would become this:**

```
[[[54,53,52], [51,50,49], [48,47,46]],
 [[45,44,43], [42,41,40], [39,38,37]],
 [[36,35,34], [33,32,31], [30,29,28]],
 [[27,26,25], [24,23,22], [21,20,19]],
 [[18,17,16], [15,14,13], [12,11,10]],
 [[ 9, 8, 7], [ 6, 5, 4], [ 3, 2, 1]]]
```

---

**This:**

```
[[[1,2]],
 [[3,4], [5]],
 [[6,7,8], [9], [10,11]],
 [[[12,13], [14,15]], [16], [17,18,19,20]],
 [21]]
```

**Would become this:**

```
[[21],
 [[20,19,18,17], [16], [[15,14], [13,12]]],
 [[11,10], [9], [8,7,6]],
 [[5], [4,3]],
 [[2,1]]]
```

---

### Bonus

This will *hopefully* encourage answers in some [object-oriented programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Object-oriented_programming_languages)...

**-50% Bytecount** If your program can take as input an array (or list) with its member's of various types (these can be in the form of objects) and successfully reverse all arrays.

**This:**

```
[["Foo",["Bar",1]],
  2,
 ["Baz"],
 [[["Qux"],3],3.14]]
```

**Would become this:**

```
[[3.14,[3,["Qux"]]],
 ["Baz"],
  2,
 [[1,"Bar"],"Foo"]]
```

Comment: In your bonus example, you treat strings as atoms. I would argue that they are sub-array, and thus should be reversed too. This is in fact what my APL solution does when fed normal strings, as APL does not have a string datatype, only character datatypes. Strings are therefore one-dimensional character arrays. If you want strings to remain in normal order, you just have to make them objects with a display form.

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ Do you believe that the -50% Bytecount is too generous? I may do something along the lines of -30% Bytecount for various data types, and something like -10% Bytecount for reversing Strings, -15% Bytecount for reversing an integer type (123 -> 321) and -15% Bytecount for reversing a floating type (3.14 -> 41.3).

Comment: I generally dislike bonuses. Reversing integers and floats is ... interesting.

Comment: Leave it for now, but next time, you may want to use the sandbox to figure out such things.

Comment: [About bonuses...](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/8478)

Comment: For the bonus, what should happen for string input? Reverse? Don't reverse? Your choice?

Comment: @MrPublic If everything should be reversed i could write this Perl program: `perl -p0e '$_=reverse;y/][/[]/'`

Comment: I am making the decision to leave the question as-is, with only the current bonus. I will not add reversing strings, integers, or floats. I will admit, I should have asked about these in the Sandbox. Due to the number of answers already, the question will not be changed and left as-is.

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, 11 - 50% = 5.5 bytes

```
L?+IbY_yMbb
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3F%2BIbY_yMbb%0AyQ&input=[[1%2C2]%2C%20[3%2C4]]&test_suite_input=[[[%201%2C%202%2C%203]%2C%20[%204%2C%205%2C%206]%2C%20[%207%2C%208%2C%209]]%2C%20[[10%2C11%2C12]%2C%20[13%2C14%2C15]%2C%20[16%2C17%2C18]]%2C%20[[19%2C20%2C21]%2C%20[22%2C23%2C24]%2C%20[25%2C26%2C27]]%2C%20[[28%2C29%2C30]%2C%20[31%2C32%2C33]%2C%20[34%2C35%2C36]]%2C%20[[37%2C38%2C39]%2C%20[40%2C41%2C42]%2C%20[43%2C44%2C45]]%2C%20[[46%2C47%2C48]%2C%20[49%2C50%2C51]%2C%20[52%2C53%2C54]]]%0A[[%22Foo%22%2C[%22Bar%22%2C1]]%2C2%2C[%22Baz%22]%2C%20[[[%22Qux%22]%2C3]%2C3.14]]%0A[[[1%2C2]]%2C%20[[3%2C4]%2C%20[5]]%2C%20[[6%2C7%2C8]%2C%20[9]%2C%20[10%2C11]]%2C%20[[[12%2C13]%2C%20[14%2C15]]%2C%20[16]%2C%20[17%2C18%2C19%2C20]]%2C%20[21]]&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3F%2BIbY_yMbb%0AyQ&input=[[1%2C2]%2C%20[3%2C4]]&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=[[[%201%2C%202%2C%203]%2C%20[%204%2C%205%2C%206]%2C%20[%207%2C%208%2C%209]]%2C%20[[10%2C11%2C12]%2C%20[13%2C14%2C15]%2C%20[16%2C17%2C18]]%2C%20[[19%2C20%2C21]%2C%20[22%2C23%2C24]%2C%20[25%2C26%2C27]]%2C%20[[28%2C29%2C30]%2C%20[31%2C32%2C33]%2C%20[34%2C35%2C36]]%2C%20[[37%2C38%2C39]%2C%20[40%2C41%2C42]%2C%20[43%2C44%2C45]]%2C%20[[46%2C47%2C48]%2C%20[49%2C50%2C51]%2C%20[52%2C53%2C54]]]%0A[[%22Foo%22%2C[%22Bar%22%2C1]]%2C2%2C[%22Baz%22]%2C%20[[[%22Qux%22]%2C3]%2C3.14]]%0A[[[1%2C2]]%2C%20[[3%2C4]%2C%20[5]]%2C%20[[6%2C7%2C8]%2C%20[9]%2C%20[10%2C11]]%2C%20[[[12%2C13]%2C%20[14%2C15]]%2C%20[16]%2C%20[17%2C18%2C19%2C20]]%2C%20[21]]&debug=0).

This defines a function `y`. The additional 3 bytes `<newline>yQ` simply call the function with the input list and therefore doesn't need to be counted towards the bytes total.

#### Explanation:

```
L?+IbY_yMbb
L             define a function y(b), that returns:
 ?+IbY           if b + [] == b (test if b is a list):
      _yMb           recursively call y on all elements in b, then reverse the list
          b      else: b
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 14 - 50% = 7 bytes

```
{∇¨⍣(×|≡⍵)⌽⍵}
```

`⌽⍵` reverse argument
`⍣(×|≡⍵)` if the argument is not an atom (sign of the [absolute] depth)...
`∇¨` ... apply the function to each element (of the reversed argument).

If `⎕ML←3` (IBM style), which is the case on systems that migrated from APL2, one byte can be saved by removing `|`.

[Try APL](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2207%A8%u2363%28%D7%7C%u2261%u2375%29%u233D%u2375%7D%281%202%29%283%204%29&run) online.

For curiosity, the [proposed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75687/reverse-an-n-dimensional-array#comment183906_75687) int and float reversing:

```
{∇¨⍣(×≡⍵){0::⌽⍵⋄⍎⌽⍕⍵}⍵}
```

The inner function:

`0::⌽⍵` if any error occurs, just return the revesed argument
`⍎⌽⍕` make into string, reverse, make into number

Answer (score 5):

## Prolog, 40 - 50% = 20 bytes

```
a(X,Y):-reverse(X,Z),maplist(a,Z,Y);X=Y.
```

This recursively calls predicate `a/2` with `maplist/3`, for each member of the list, until `reverse/2` fails (i.e. last element wasn't a list).

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 40 - 50% = 20

```
f=lambda x:map(f,x)[::-1]if"">x>[]else x
```

Only some minor modifications needed from the basic way to do it are needed to get the bonus. Uses the fact that all lists are less than the empty string, and all numbers are less than the empty list.

[All test cases](https://ideone.com/kLmvdI)

Comment: Just a note that the version without the bonus is `f=lambda x:map(f,x)[::-1]if x>[]else x`.

Answer (score 3):

### Emacs Lisp, 46 bytes * 0.5 = 23

```
(defun g(x)(if(atom x)x(mapcar'g(reverse x))))
```

Usage example: `(g '((1 2) 3 (four 5)))` -> `((5 four) 3 (2 1))`

Classic recursive approach: if the argument isn't a list, take it unchanged, if it's a list, map the function over the reverse of the list.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 34/2=17 bytes

```
Quiet[Reverse//@#]/.Reverse->(#&)&
```

Or just `Reverse//@#&` if you want a ton of errors and `Reverse`s everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure 43/2=21.5 bytes

```
(defn f[x](if(coll? x)(reverse(map f x))x))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 - 50% = 2.5 bytes

```
ċ↔↰ᵐ|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU@7TsNAEOzzFdHVI@R93NmukCjoqU8ukiiCAmQpCIlnkyISoqHgQ2hAiJofsX/E7J4RzXl2drwzs96tNhd3l/05Tw/D93NYrLeb/mp7vQg2HY@H93G/NzR8fdr7NHy8Tj8v4@HNFoYfpykvcyZwhyzQroONPkOMUUQk@9Zo0NrONhWIQC4nASkoOkygGtTMkhZcgckwM1jA6jCCE7guEm7ALaRyU4KYmbuJQiIkFYnUkAbSeooKSlD3VMuo0FgkmqA1tHG@RawQ3TMyoiBalf8u80F4jPnPBGtkwK@XRoXNxCAPMtcqvfzxZiitnGP6OxxO@z4gh5PVLsBJLsN9KLfC2c2tITsnR2Rhlt0v)

```
         The input
ċ        which is a list
 ↔       reversed
   ᵐ     with each element
  ↰      passed through this same predicate
    |    is the output. If the input isn't a list,
         it is the output.
```

Since `↔` can also reverse strings and integers, we have to explicitly fail non-lists with `ċ`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

-50% bonus

```
#0/@Reverse@*List@@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVA9T8MwFNz7K6xE6oAOmvfhfAygiIGJAVgRQ1SlIkOp1AaEsPLbg/2SLtbZd@/enY/d@Nkfu3HYd/Phfs6LXfvW//TnS9/ePA@XsW3z7fxyHr7G9/z24dDmH9tdGzYhEHhCEOg0IV6DIziGkwkuOIXzcKXhCq6Ga5LMxbECRCBOFAlIQd5wCapA9VXWgAswJYoZLGA17MEluFplXIMbSJEoIQhDLIAoxEPKVSYVpIY0idICSlALoDG@Qv0q0xJaQWujGvgC3gJ4hhf42HSpmqqvxrBUV4MSFWzaNlnVlQnEIIu2NF4q25law/ouWqZlTfZ0OmUI2WN3zrD4xA@Ogvjyl6222ev3b8TRWe4oBtxM8z8)

Only works on nested `List`s of atoms. Reverse a list, then reverse its elements. `@@` and `/@` are no-ops on atoms.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 42 - 50% = 21 bytes

My score is perfect in so many ways. Implements a function `r` which recursively applies itself to the members of its input.

```
r=a=>Array.isArray(a)?a.reverse().map(r):a
```

If we assume no object has the property `pop`, then this becomes (31 - 50% = 15.5), thanks to dev-null:

```
r=a=>a.pop?a.reverse().map(r):a
```

Or, if we assume the object has a sane `reverse` property, we could do that as well (35 - 50% = 17.5):

```
r=a=>a[R="reverse"]?a[R]().map(r):a
```

Comment: I guess you could safely check for an array like this: `a.pop?a.reverse().map(r):a`. Assuming there is no need to handle `void 0` and custom objects.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <s>111</s> 99 * .5 = <s>55.5</s> 49.5 bytes

```
function r(a)local t={}for i,v in next,a do t[#a+1-i]=type(v)=="table"and r(v)or v end return t end
```

Good bit of recursion

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 20 bytes * 50% = 10

```
{_`0='[={W%{F}%}&}:F
```

Defines the named block `F` which can be applied to an array on top of the stack (or anything else, in which case it's a no-op).

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B%5B%5B1%202%5D%5D%20%5B%5B3%204%5D%20%5B5%5D%5D%20%5B%5B6%207%208%5D%20%5B9%5D%20%5B10%2011%5D%5D%20%5B%5B%5B12%2013%5D%20%5B14%2015%5D%5D%20%5B16%5D%20%5B17%2018%2019%2020%5D%5D%20%5B21%5D%5D%0A%0A%7B_%600%3D'%5B%3D%7BW%25%7BF%7D%25%7D%26%7D%3AF%0A%0A~p)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 38 bytes

**(and a bonus I guess, but Clojure is a dynamic language so it comes for free)**

```
(fn f[x](if(seq? x)(map f(into()x))x))
```

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75733/59617) is a good start but didn't employ these optimizations:

- Define an anonymous function with `fn` instead of a named one with `defn`. But we still need a "scoped" name `f` for recursion
- Take input as a list instead of vector, then we can use `seq?` instead of `coll?`
- Use `(into () ...)` instead of `reverse`
- Reverse `x` before mapping, we don't need as many spaces then

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>40</s> 38 -50% = 19 bytes

```clj
(fn r[s](if(coll? s)(map r(rseq s))s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYpBCoAgFAWv8nD1XVoHiM4hQmEahql9Dbq9CbOZYWzM18uu0@E8vk4@gXU1FDzZHOOCKuneC5i4umeYHHRJhUNqMYE@bFpBrKhtpFNAT1AGsxnbDw)

A translation of [the JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75692/107299). Matched the score with the best Clojure answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) + [free](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.7/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html), 8.5 bytes (17 bytes -50% bonus)

In order to represent a ragged list in Haskell we use a free monad of lists.  We use the [free](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.7/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) library to get these free monads.

```haskell
hoistFree reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRS8MwFIXf@ysOrLAWVkF9ctg@DgQVEd9kyF1728bVZCSpQ9TfXtPUthN8Sjjn5jv3pCaz56bpPpMFbklWLVWMR5L7@6ePAxssku@gIEvYaGaUoABI8dBq9tevQY9KRONAHAeBZqspt1ivcackFU5PswmBJPOkcSoacLEDO6nV8tTzj8j0JhlkmZ/prSColTDW@y5n08rcKo2qT4pKpalpQGdjXtXzk2mH3XSvsDsBvczLzDVnu/yzz1D91L0OfTMTd1U665rfWRvu3khIpO7XkgQ3KJRcWhxJWliFoxaWYWvGQQsnFVwKKaxQEq7LEGXcGOMoXLHxe4TFa2s8Ia853zthaeBiepIWVW2hdMHahQ7ccHoauurhAH72Rc9XQ@GL3/Ny9Z97td12Pw)

### Explanation

`hoistFree` takes a natural transformation from some functor \$F\$ to another functor \$G\$ and makes a natural transformation from \$\mathrm{Free}(F)\$ to \$\mathrm{Free}(G)\$.  Here the natural transformation is reverse, from lists to lists.

Because `hoistFree` must work with any natural transformation we know it must apply `reverse` exactly once to every sublist.  For example imagine we had a natural transformation:

```haskell
newtype Reversed f a
  = Reversed (f a)

reverse' :: [a] -> Reversed [] a
reverse' =
  Reversed . reverse
```

This is functionally identical to `reverse` but the types prove it must be applied exactly once to every list.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 - 50% = 16 bytes

Recursive function. Using `rescue` to catch the `NoMethodError` that triggers when trying to `reverse` a number or `map` a string turns out to be 2 bytes shorter than checking if the input is an array via `a==[*a]`.

```ruby
f=->a{a.reverse.map(&f)rescue a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6xOlGvKLUstag4VS83sUBDLU2zKLU4uTRVIbH2f4FCml5yYk6ORmpZYo5CcIiLpx9QcWKK5v/oaCW3/HwlnWglp8QiJR3D2FgdLgUFIyABEqlSAnGjgYoCSyuAbGMg0jM0iY0FAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 27 -50% = 13.5

```julia
!x=x
!x::Array=reverse(.!x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HCtoJLscLKyrGoKLHStii1LLWoOFVDT7FC839KZnFBTmKlhoJidLSSW36@kk60klNikZKOYWysDpeCghGQAIlUKYG40UBFgaUVQLYxEOkZmsTGav4HAA)