# Sort every dimension

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting

Given a multidimensional, rectangular array of nonnegative integers, sort it at every depth (lexicographically), starting from the innermost.

For example, with this array:

```
[ [ [5, 1, 4], 
    [10, 7, 21] ], 
  [ [9, 20, 2],
    [4, 2, 19] ] ]
```

You'd sort at the deepest first:

```
[ [ [1, 4, 5], 
    [7, 10, 21] ], 
  [ [2, 9, 20],
    [2, 4, 19] ] ]
```

Then sort at the next depth, lexicographically:

```
[ [ [1, 4, 5], 
    [7, 10, 21] ], 
  [ [2, 4, 19], 
    [2, 9, 20] ] ]
```

lexicographic comparison of arrays means comparing the first element, and if they're equal comparing the second, and so on all the way down the line. Here we see that `[2, 4, 19]` is less than `[2, 9, 20]` because although the first elements are equal (2) the second aren't - 4 < 9.

Finally, sort at the top depth (lexicographically):

```
[ [ [1, 4, 5], 
    [7, 10, 21] ], 
  [ [2, 4, 19], 
    [2, 9, 20] ] ]
```

The first one is less than the second, because `[1, 4, 5]` is less than `[2, 4, 19]` because 1 is less than 2.

You may take the lengths of dimensions and/or depth of the array as well.

### Testcases

```
[2, 1] -> [1, 2]
[[[10, 5, 9], [6, 4, 4]], [[2, 6, 3], [3, 3, 2]], [[3, 8, 6], [1, 5, 6]]] -> [[[1, 5, 6], [3, 6, 8]], [[2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 6]], [[4, 4, 6], [5, 9, 10]]]
[[[6, 9], [12, 17]], [[9, 6], [9, 8]]] -> [[[6, 9], [8, 9]], [[6, 9], [12, 17]]]
[[[9, 1], [2, 5]], [[8, 5], [3, 5]]] -> [[[1, 9], [2, 5]], [[3, 5], [5, 8]]]
```

Comment: This is gonna sound weird, but can I assume the integers are smaller than `0x10ffff`?

Comment: @taRadvylfsriksushilani Aha, Unicode magic…

Comment: Can we assume the numbers are a single digit?

Comment: @Seggan nope. (filler)

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes (@SurculoseSputum)

```
def f(L):L>f<map(f,L)<L.sort()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBasMwEEXp1qcYsrJACZEdu3aIs-zKNxCiGGoRgWsLx0nIWbrxpvQWvUd7ms5ISiAFw3yN3_z50seXvU6HoU_m-fM06WXx_dZq0HHNtvVe794bG2tes129Og7jFDMP_dSXg-laENsIwPABKiCyPTcdH5vLq-ntCeHV0XZmihew3MOCMWR1bKjY0fQTDFVlOJjIe86_Ty8y4SAU4VJwSFQkpRRrDhmHUnGQOYcNfoo0sXhOSadYiXd9VAX-Ii3caK6U95T3hp_B8eLulQYvL3Pf37iFjqcMmG6NZhQrD5EERX72dBnQ0vnedt7Igqrj_s86QzIP-zOPFaR80uzhCuUjlwYu82vDe_4B)

##### Old [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes (@ovs)

```
f=lambda s:s>f<s.sort(key=f)or s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZDRaoMwFIbZbZ_i0KsIaWm0Oi21l2PvEMJwTGmYVTFpS59lN96MPdP2NDsnSQstCPlz_P7__Pr1M1zsvu_iafo-2maR_0JTttXh_aMCszG7ZmuWph8t-6wvZRP1I5jAvZ73uq1BbGYAmvdQwqEaWH2qWj5W5zfdDUfLoqUZWm3ZHBY7mEcRssOoO8vQUZYN0zjyedPf04uMOQhFqBQcYjWTUooVh5RDoTjIjMMaH0WaWLwnpBM8iXdzVDm-Ii2cNVPKZ8rbwHvQnt-ykpDlZebna7fQ8dQB260wjGploZKgys-eLgJauNzrziuZ0-m4R68LpPCwP_VYTso3Te8-objnksClfm34n_8)

##### Old [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes (@ovs)

```
f=lambda s:s>[]<s.sort(key=f)or s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZDRaoMwFIbZbZ_itFcR0tJodVpqL8feIYThmNIwq2LSlT7LbrwZe6btaXZOkhY6EPLn-P3_-fXze7jYQ9_F0_R1ss0y_5k3ZVsdX98qMFuzl2pnVqYfLXuvL2UT9SOYAD6fD7qtQWxnAJr3UMKxGlj9UbV8rM4vuhtOlkUrM7TasgUs97CIImSHUXeWoaMsG6Zx5POm34cnGXMQilApOMRqJqUUaw4ph0JxkBmHDT6KNLF4T0gneBLv5qhyfEVaOGumlM-Ut4H3oD2_ZSUhy8vMzzduoeOpA7ZbYxjVykIlQZUfPV0EtHC5151XMqfTcf-9LpDCw_7UYzkp3zS9-4TinksCl_q14X_-AQ)

##### Old [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```
f=lambda s:s>=[]<s.sort(key=f)or s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZDRaoMwFIbZbZ_i4FWEtDRaXSxLL8feIYThmNIwq2LSlT7LbrwZe6btaZaTpIUWhPw5fv9_fv36Gc92P_TZPH8fbbvkv0kruvrw9l6D2ZqdkOrJrMwwWfLRnEWbDhOYSL6c9rprgG0XAJoOIOBQj6T5rDs61adX3Y9HS9KVGTttSQLLHSRp6thx0r0lziFES7Qbhbz57-FZZhSYQlQyCplaSCnZmkJBoVIUZElh4x6FGll3z1Hn7kTez53i7hVq5q2lUiFTXgfB4-z8mpXHrCDLMN_4hZ7HDq7d2oVhrTJWYlj5MdBVRCufe9l5ITmenrv3-kAMj_uLgHFUoWlx8wnVLZdHrghr4__8Bw)

This works by side-effect (of in-place sort). It uses comparison to `[]` as a type check and chained comparison to short circuit (in-place sort returns `None`, so the chained comparison will always fail)

Comment: Functions are allowed to output [by modifying their argument](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/64121), which should save a couple of bytes. And you can use a different object to compare to instead of `[]` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @ovs thanks! Re your first point: I think we still need to return s otherwise sort will be asked to sort a bunch of `None`s if there is any nesting. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ovs Re the second: which object did you have in mind? Is there one that only takes one byte?

Comment: For the comparison you can use the function `f` itself, which according to Python 2 weird ordering is more than any integer but less than a list. Regarding the output method I missed that you used the return values for sorting, my initial idea for solving this problem was using `map` to recurse and sorting afterwards, where you get away with returning `None`.

Comment: Can do `def f(L):L>f<map(f,L)<L.sort()` for 30 bytes. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBasMwEEXp1qcYsrJACZEdu3aIs-zKNxCiGGoRgWsLx0nIWbrxpvQWvUd7ms5ISiAFw3yN3_z50seXvU6HoU_m-fM06WXx_dZq0HHNtvVe794bG2tes129Og7jFDMP_dSXg-laENsIwPABKiCyPTcdH5vLq-ntCeHV0XZmihew3MOCMWR1bKjY0fQTDFVlOJjIe86_Ty8y4SAU4VJwSFQkpRRrDhmHUnGQOYcNfoo0sXhOSadYiXd9VAX-Ii3caK6U95T3hp_B8eLulQYvL3Pf37iFjqcMmG6NZhQrD5EERX72dBnQ0vnedt7Igqrj_s86QzIP-zOPFaR80uzhCuUjlwYu82vDe_4B)

Comment: Great answer, I was wondering what is the exact effect on the ordering of elements when passing `f` to `key`. If anyone would care to explain, I would be grateful.

Comment: @solid.py It rearranges the original list in such a way that if you were to apply `map(f,_)` afterwards you would get a sorted list,

Comment: @loopywalt I've never seen passing a recursive function as `key` to `sort()` before. Could you tell me at a single iteration, what is being passed at the `key` argument, (e.g. is it a sorted sublist, the sorting function itself, some other implicit key)? Sorry if this question is trivial.

Comment: @solid.py I'm not 100% sure how this is actually implemented, but I'm fairly confident the following is a valid mental model: The key function, `f` say, is applied to each element of the sort argument `l`. The transformed list is then argsorted and the resulting order applied to the original list; one way to think of it is to form triples `(f(l[0]),0,l[0]), f(l[1]),1,l[1]),...), sort them and then return the last elements of the sorted triples. - the present case is special in that we ultimately do not want the original elements but the transformed ones. ...

Comment: @solid.py  To enforce this behaviour we let `f` act in-place. However, we also need `f` to return the updated values because as we just learned `sort` sorts based on the values returned by `f`.

Comment: @loopywalt Thanks for this detailed explanation, this cleared things up for me.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ßŒḊ¡€Ṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZAxDsIwDEX3nsISa5CapgnJwj2QlZEF9QKsLEiMTGwIZg5AVyoOUi4S7DhUgBTJv87z9282667bpjScn8fxfnhcXrvb2F/TsCdBrf5EdZUSVtgo0FHBDOZLQK2giRUi6lqBVRDoBp2Clk5kzTh9G9aGKvO5T8rTFWudR12Mky1OPRkjBz/ZmWIn0km/zTszzzEoY01@nMyVVJqDL4QOBQ3Z92vtB/ZcM/o/nj2DvAFHsIJ5VhLW/v9I@EVNQa0sr@Ib)

### How it works

```
ßŒḊ¡€Ṣ - Main link f(M). Takes a multidimensional array M on the left
    €  - Over each inner element E of M:
 ŒḊ    -   Get its depth, D
ß  ¡   -   Call f(E) D times
     Ṣ - Sort the result
```

Essentially, as sorting is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), `f` is also idempotent, and so we can apply it as many times as we want with no extra side effects. Therefore, we iterate over each element of `M`, depth-wise, apply `f` to it, then sort the result.

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 18 bytes

```
Sort//@#/.Sort->D&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2/CoMwEMZ3XyPg9Fkbo2kyVBz6AAXH0iFIpQ5akGzhfPX0ktLpfnffn1udf79W55fJxfkax8/u63oQ9SlR1d/KeN@XzT9E1c@DeJbHOLntCEVoIAlFCEGe0cESgkaLlhhY01AMCgpNvigYaAbJXk30S@ock9x0ySabLRbmb7DpB7d1WTY8UydvVFD8Ag)

Essentially copied from [this earlier answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186798/81203). Relies on the array being rectangular; otherwise, `LexicographicSort` (introduced 12.3) is required instead

```
Sort//@#            sort all levels
        /.Sort->D   un-Sort atoms
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation?  Normally I've seen `//` used like a pipe, and `/@` as map, but I can't make sense of `//@` here.  Also, how does `D` (derivative) come into play?  Is it something else here?

Comment: @Jonah `//@` is [`MapAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAll.html), and `D` is identity when called on a single argument. That last part is necessary since e.g. `Sort[1]` does not become `1`.

Comment: Thanks! Followup q:  Why is the identity version of `D` not documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html)?  Or does it somehow fall out of the 1st or 3rd case?

Comment: @Jonah To be honest, I first found out while doing a brute-force search for identities. It does make sense in context of the 3rd case, though the presentation does imply that there needs to be at least one variable; deriving w.r.t. no variables is the same as not performing a derivation.

Comment: It is curious that`D` doesn't throw an error when not given a differentiation variable. For example, you could also say `Integrate@f` is like doing an integration wrt no variables; but that returns an error rather than `f`.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>18</s> 12 bytes

Anonymous prefix lambda. Takes list of lists… as argument.

```apl
{×≡⍵:∧∇¨⍵⋄⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sPT3/UufBR71arRx3LH3W0H1oBZD/qbgGStf/TgEo0HvX2PepqftS75lHvlkPrjR@1TQTqDg5yBpIhHp7BmkDaK9jf73@aerSRjoJhrDqXrq4uF5AXHW1ooKNgqqNgGaujEG2mo2ACRLEgNkghkG8MYhsDaR0FI4g4kGUBlAKxDcFazWJjkQ00gxpmCLLJHKLHEqoBSFugqrYEOQcoA1RsClFrAWJBLDUFqQUA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument is `⍵`:

`×` [if] signum of
 `≡` depth of
 `⍵` argument
 `:` (i.e. if the argument has depth) then:

`∧` sort the
  `∇` recursion on
  `¨` each of
  `⍵`  the argument

`⋄` else:

`⍵` return the argument

Answer (score 4):

## [SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/), <s>72</s> <s>59</s> 49 bytes

```
f([H|T],S):-f(H,Q),f(T,R),msort([Q|R],S).
f(E,E).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89C4MwEIb3/oqMCZzSaLWxSyfB1ZgtZGyKYGtRwcX/bu@MghC497177iO/oe/6dzTO7bp6bqvFOGjEI/K8glqA5wa0gM/YDxO39aKpGl88L6EU8fpEzibApAOGNOattfIKLANWYM7mwG74HGkC0aekU4zAkpBHpbBEWm6tuaOCPgbm@zBJm@6hp9gbMKqNbg66COfQtiywilRYmm2sQXYe2unF8ehvdxh9Ns3ZGPzrHw)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>70</s> 64 bytes

```js
f=x=>x.sort(g=(a,b)=>1/a?a-b:f(a).some((c,i)=>a=g(c,f(b)[i]))*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BDoIwDEDvfsWOnRnoQBA007sHPXhcdhiEkRkUA8To189OOBuSJX1b29fupl@6Lzv7HIJX5pwRb3F4h33bDVAL0Kyg4sBX@qiDYmdAU0zdK4CSWUxoUSMZKKi0itKlpq5sH33bVGHT1nC6Xs5hP3T2UVvzAQMyYoRjId0v/tdJydeMJIzkihGZMrLBozx7Bd5jzzFGRqLxHSnDlGf@a02VmjcqncZwv912tOWTCmM215P7z2EPapLRknkaF00mi/sC)

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718).*

Comment: `f=x=>x.sort(g=(a,b)=>1/a?a-b:f(a).some((c,i)=>a=g(c,f(b)[i]))*a)`

Comment: @tsh Nice one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
λ-[vxs
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLOuy1bdnhzIiwiIiwiW1tbMTAsIDUsIDldLCBbNiwgNCwgNF1dLCBbWzIsIDYsIDNdLCBbMywgMywgMl1dLCBbWzMsIDgsIDZdLCBbMSwgNSwgNl1dXSJd)

*-5 thanks to @emanresuA in vychat*

### Explained

```
λ-[vxs
λ      # a lambda that takes a single argument n and:
 -     #   subtracts n from itself (scalars return 0 which is falsey, lists return a list of 0s which is truthy) - borrowed from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241658/78850
  [    #  and if that item is a list
   vx  #    call this lambda on each item
     s #    and sort the result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

```
f(a)=if(#a',vecsort(apply(f,a)),a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU3bCgIhEP2VYXtIYRZyt734UD8i8yCRIUSJRdDX28xqoMy5ziSfY39LpQTl9SkGtfN7/Fwvr2d@K5/S/asCeq35l0o99GdIOT7Yh05IB1LWCM4NCIYEOHNAmBCssBnhyI@oRZiPgkeeCEPVGa1sCTZbdaZqSH1bY2T7UkXbojzXf8624xybqrQKqodYIdLlBw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>47</s>  36 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Dialfrost, and 9 bytes thanks to @loopywalt

```python
f=lambda l:l*0!=0==l.sort(key=f)or l
```

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7NCoMwDIDvPkWOLYSx6nQ66JOUHqpVJutUtBefvmusDCGQr82Xn2X373kqQhikM9/WGnAvvy89c1xKN24ezGTB3bZ59ezT73Lg8wouGJCgcgShs5ZQKXFHKBEajaAqhEcMTUxWfBfERcwIefqPVMcSsThaK6111qVp1TlJ0I5namhOO@aaVJvUhq7A45oyiTVRWleSmC3rOHk2MMP5n9sLdxe2nIcf)

Comment: cheaper type check [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7bCoMwDEDf/Yo82pGNVafTQb@k5KHaycbqBeeLX981VoYQyGlzcpnW5TUOufedcqZvrAH3cKezVEqTGSy4y3ecl/TzXFUnxhmcN6BAZwiSkoZRa3lFKBBqQtAlwi0EMbMV3jlzHjJCFv8DVaHELLfWkoiSNk4r90mSd9xjQ73bIVes2qjWfAVu1xRRrJjiuoLFZJrfw5J2qRHiz82B2wNbIfwP)

Comment: @loopywalt Thank you so much, I'm also trying out `l*0==[]` atm, I think it achieves the same of reducing the list to an empty state, with one byte less.

Comment: Good point! And you can save another one going `l*0!=0`.

Comment: While you're at it: [36](https://tio.run/##TY7NDoMgDIDvPkV3g6VZRKfDJTwJ4YA6s2VMjePi0zMqZjFp0g/69Wde/XMayxAG5eyn7S24uzvnJ5Ur5S7fafHs/VjVwKcFXLCgQBcIwmQtodYiR6gQGoOga4RrDENMVnyXxGXMCEX6jyRjiVhsrbUxJuvStHqfJGjHLTU0ux2zJLVPakNX4HZNlURJlNZVJGbz8ho9G5jl/M/tgbsD95yHHw).

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
f=->b{b*0==0?b:b.map(&f).sort}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6pOknLwNbWwD7JKkkvN7FAQy1NU684v6ik9n@BQlo0EBga6CiY6ihYxuooRJvpKJgAUSyIHW2kowDkG4PYxkBaR8EIIg5kWQClQGxDsFazWCD4DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 30 bytes

```
[:><@#\.@$(4 :'/:"x~y')&.>/@,<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NTsMwEITvfopRi0gibd04joNtlSgCiVPFgavxCbVCXLjChVcP658iFcmWx@tvZtcf60Y2Z9x7NCD08Lx3Eo8vx6c1@PmwbF/lctOO8M3eb75@vpvuVs77hQ5rJ54fJMTp7f0TZ7QOivwA05FvLQx5zVpwYi9CCKonrsFFQpgII6@YdBgIfNdJaz4JQ6mzsvyUtMrWKcaI3YwUVgvFw3b7l6VrVpFTqY@5YebTDATVc1gaa6ojKebVXaFdRV3OvfS8kDadmfvvzYEpvPY3BbNJlUnN1RfcNacrZ0pb0a2/)

Uses a single fold to explicitly sort each rank, in order.  Requires an explicit verb since rank `"` is a conjunction.

*Note: Could save 1 byte with `{{ }}` but it fails on TIO's J version.*

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>23</sup> 17 bytes, port of Adam's recursive APL solution

```
[:/:~$:^:(#@$)"_1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BigIxEETv8xWFKzgDrU4mZkwaFGFhT3vaa4geZGXZi3/gr4/dSRQUElLpvKru/E@z1eKCHWMBQg@WvVzh8@f7a4q85tucj9x@HObd7GSmrvk9/11xQRtgiAe4jrj1cMRWdCP@vokxmp6khpAIcSRsZCXVcSDI3aq2chKGUhfl5Um1ydYxpYTlHhpWC8Ujdv/MsjWryLHUN7lh5nUGguklTMca60hGeLMtdKhoyLmPng/S65m5d28O1PDa3xXMqyqTupcvhFfOVs6Vtk033QE)

*-6 thanks to ovs!*

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY/BigIxEETv8xWFKzgDrU4mZkwaFGFhT3vaa4geZGXZi3/gr4/dSRQUElLpvKru/E@z1eKCHWMBQg@WvVzh8@f7a4q85tucj9x@HObd7GSmrvk9/11xQRtgiAe4jrj1cMRWdCP@vokxmp6khpAIcSRsZCXVcSDI3aq2chKGUhfl5Um1ydYxpYTlHhpWC8Ujdv/MsjWryLHUN7lh5nUGguklTMca60hGeLMtdKhoyLmPng/S65m5d28O1PDa3xXMqyqTupcvhFfOVs6Vtk033QE) on the second one by using `^:` instead of `@.`.

Comment: Nice one.  Now, if you wish to play hard mode, please have a shot at [this monstrosity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241640/15469).

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 15 bytes

```haskell
x=Fe<sr<m x*~|p
```

Takes input as a free monad of lists.

### Explanation

In Haskell we use a free monad of lists.  A very simplified definition would look like:

```
data Ragged a
  = Pur a
  | Fe [Ragged a]
```

It's either a terminal element (wrapped in `Pur`) or a list of more ragged lists (wrapped in `Fe`).

We could write the code then like:

```haskell
x (Fe y)=
  Fe < sr < m x $ y
x (Pur y)=
  p y
```

In the `Fe` case we map `x` across the input to sort all lower levels, sort the result and wrap it back in a free.

In the pure case we just wrap it back in a pure using `p`.

Now hgl has a special operator to do this sort of case for us.  We use the `*~|` operator  which is the equivalent to a pattern match on the cases of a `Free`.

So now we rewrite both options as a function `Fe<sr<m x` and `p` and supply them as args to `*~|`.

We can't get rid of the `x=` this time because the definition is recursive.

### Reflections

Wow, I couldn't get this one in point free.  That's probably an issue.

`hoF` for `hoistFree` *nearly* is useful here.  If we just wanted to for example reverse every level `hoF rv` would work fine. But we can't just place `sr` in there instead of `rv`. `sr` needs the elements to be `Ord`.  Instead we have to do this.

There should probably be a version of hoist which allows this sort of thing.  Would save 9 bytes here.

```haskell
maF ::
  ( Functor f
  , Functor g
  )
    => (f (Free g a) -> g (Free g a)) -> Free f a -> Free g a
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 13 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
⊢{∧⚇}´≡-↕∘≡
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqie+KIp+Kah/CdlajwnZWpfcK04omhLeKGleKImOKJoQo+KOKLiCDCtyBGIOKAokpzKcKo4p+oICJbIFsgWzUsIDEsIDRdLCAKICAgIFsxMCwgNywgMjFdIF0sIAogIFsgWzksIDIwLCAyXSwKICAgIFs0LCAyLCAxOV0gXSBdIgoiWzIsMV0iCiJbW1sxMCwgNSwgOV0sIFs2LCA0LCA0XV0sIFtbMiwgNiwgM10sIFszLCAzLCAyXV0sIFtbMywgOCwgNl0sIFsxLCA1LCA2XV1dIgoiW1tbNiwgOV0sIFsxMiwgMTddXSwgW1s5LCA2XSwgWzksIDhdXV0iCiJbW1s5LCAxXSwgWzIsIDVdXSwgW1s4LCA1XSwgWzMsIDVdXV0iCgrin6k=)

`{∧⍟≡¨}` is a translation of J, `{×≡?∧¨;}` is a shorter direct translation of dyalog extended, but using the depth modifier is cooler.

-2 from Adam.

Comment: `⊢{∧⚇}´≡-↕∘≡`

Comment: The recursive version could be [`{∧⍟=˘}`](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge+KIp/CdlYrijZ89y5jwnZWpfQoKCkY+PuKAokpzICJbW1s5LCAxXSwgWzIsIDVdXSwgW1s4LCA1XSwgWzMsIDVdXV0i) if you take an actual array

Comment: question says depth, so dunno if that will be right

Comment: The input is a *rectangular array*, so it can be represented by an array. And `=` and `˘` for an array are the same as `≡` and `¨` for an equivalent nested list. This is the same as the 17 byter on the J answer. (That means `{∧⍟≡¨}` works for your current input format)

Comment: ah i see, i'll put it in

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"Ð˜Êi®δ.V}{"©.V
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f6fCE03MOd2UeWndui15YbbXSoZV6Yf//R0dHm@koWMbqKEQbGukoGJrHgpjRljoKZiAGkLaIjY0FAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##NY07DsIwEESvErkeRbEdO3GVW6SxXIBEkYoCCSlCtBRUiJoL0FBxgqRE4hBcxMzy2WZnd@fNrjeL5bDK27FTxetwLlQ3ZjWfHpf5OEy3573s9zs1Xcs@I0eWg0adEHWFBkYnyhhgKhiqGgY6JC6LSCUtitMh8OpRExXAwMNSWFhysrFo4SWWXv8NiAQE00xqfn/EEtD@DUF@MM19zi27ZHJK6Q0).

**Explanation:**

As mentioned in similar challenges, 05AB1E lacks recursive functions unfortunately, making it pretty long by mimicking the behavior with a string and 05AB1E-eval.

```python
"..."       # Push the recursive string mentioned below
     ©      # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
      .V    # Evaluate and execute it as 05AB1E code
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)

Ð˜Ê         # Check that this is the maximum depth of this (inner) list:
Ð           #  Triplicate the current list
 ˜          #  Flatten the top copy
  Ê         #  Check that the top two copies are NOT equal
   i    }   # If this is truthy, so we've reached the maximum depth:
     δ      #  Map over each inner item:
    ® .V    #   Do a recursive call (by 05AB1E-evaluating string `®`)
         {  # Sort the list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 22 bytes

```julia
!x::Int=x
!x=sort(.!x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BjoMgEIbvPsXoCRNKSq2uNrH3PewTEA4kZRM3hBplN7y9ywBtosSEf4Zv/vn9@TWT4n7bSn@7fVo3@qL04/pcHGGlr7fv5wJmshomC4tWD9QrqQsIR1ENI@g/ZRj50k6xWS2rZmSdzeQIkhSq072q68TPy2SdsUTty/JQB9MRjs2KVXWh7WMTFwpcwukOglO4yEIIwc8UWgqDpCA6CtfwSdTIhrpB3YQb@dgPqg9PqHkc7aRMnuLdSDNhvH97NdkryS71r3Fh5DFDSHcOZhiry5E4Rv5I9JDRIfq@dr7IHu/IHWejIZrn/W3CelQpabv7hWHPNZlr09p/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 49 bytes

```
⊞υθＦυＦιＦ⁼κ⁺⟦⟧κ⊞υκＷ∧υ⊟υ«≔⟦⟧ηＷι⊞η⊟ιＷ⁻ηιＦ№η⌊κ⊞ι⌊κ»Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LCsIwEDzbr9hjAhF8o3gS8Sj0XnoovrI0bW1j9CB@e5y0FXUJ7GQeyRx01hyqzHgfO6uFU1TLdXSuGhJOUru537vaZcaKXFFsnBVJqiiXUtInmCP40GxOJDblMTBxdcUrsDyjwcZavpRtSsM46J3c53XnZvmj7bnEP1DAdhW2lStvgYHEhSvEtwD/kevoFcUNw7zN7E3UYLxPMOORormiFWokC0UznDTgZKII92nAU2xFk44HWkIKeNxGFynGD@/mDQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs using Charcoal's default output format, where depth 1 arrays print their elements on their own line but the arrays themselves are double-spaced from each other, then depth 2 arrays are triple-spaced from each other etc. Explanation:

```
⊞υθ
```

Start enumerating all of the arrays at each depth.

```
ＦυＦι
```

Process all elements of each array.

```
Ｆ⁼κ⁺⟦⟧κ⊞υκ
```

If this element is itself an array then push it to the list of all arrays.

```
Ｗ∧υ⊟υ«
```

Process the list in reverse order.

```
≔⟦⟧ηＷι⊞η⊟ι
```

Move the elements from this array into a temporary array.

```
Ｗ⁻ηιＦ№η⌊κ⊞ι⌊κ
```

Move them back in ascending order.

```
»Ｉθ
```

Output the final array.

Comment: neil how ru so good at this language and quick qns, how do you understand it? its not in english?

Comment: @DialFrost Verbose mode is almost readable. `-v` tells Charcoal to convert from Verbose mode to proper Charcoal, and `-l` tells it to print that before executing it.

Comment: oh ic thats why although i still dont understand this language haha

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$7\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 5.762 bytes

```
!#lxKMX
```

[See the README to see how to run this](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig/blob/master/README.md)

This answer uses that fact that programs = functions in Fig, so I can invoke the program from within the program.

```
!#lxKMX # Takes the list as input
!       # If
 #lx    # The input is a list
     M  # Map the list
      X # By this function (i.e. the program itself)
    K   # Then sort the resulting list
        # If the input is not a list, simply return the input
```

Comment: But [Vyxal does](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnsW7IiwiIiwiIl0=) beat this

Comment: @emanresuA but not posted :)